# Source code syntax highlighting on Stack Overflow WMD

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting, editor, source-code

I was wondering how Stack Overflow ([WMD editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71822/wheres-the-wmd-editor-open-source-project)) solves syntax highlighting on source code snippets.

I understand that if text is marked as code it gets that `<pre> CODE </pre>` tags and that the wmd then recognizes this as code snippet. But how is the syntax highlighting itself done?

I noticed that all this must happen based on JavaScript and no Ajax and server based stuff is involved at all.

How is this done? How is the programming language of a code piece detected? Does this work like an *exact* science (meaning code is really detected as, for example, Ruby code) or is is code highlighted done by a 'generic' code syntax highlighting?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-does-so-syntax-highlight-citations-so-well/14670

Comment: It's `<code><pre> CODE </pre></code>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange sites are using Google's Prettify to do the syntax coloring. Prettify uses common language patterns to determine syntax coloring.

For further information see [here](https://github.com/google/code-prettify).

The authoritative source on the languages that are understood by Prettify are in [prettify.js](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/05ad1b76f8af1232da963c17bad144107b07e59a/js-modules/prettify.js).

Here is an extract:

> The lexer should work on a number of
>   languages including C and friends,
>   Java, Python, Bash, SQL, HTML, XML,
>   CSS, JavaScript, and Makefiles.   It
>   works passably on Ruby, PHP and AWK
>   and a decent subset of Perl, but,
>   because of commenting conventions,
>   doesn't work on Smalltalk, Lisp-like,
>   or CAML-like languages.
>       If there's a language not mentioned here, then I don't know it,
>   and don't know whether it works.  If
>   it has a C-like, Bash-like, or
>   XML-like syntax then it should work
>   passably.

Comment: So it is not exact science everytime but some kind generic, right?

Do you know which languages are supported by prettify?

Comment: I see. Thx for your answer!