# How does Stackoverflow's Code sample option work?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I am not asking for the code its just general discussion.I want to know that when we paste our code how does it automatically gets the color of code exactly as we copied.

For Example:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from student_details", con)
```

how does it know that the **"New" and "SqlCommand" is blue colored** and

Comment: this might help you: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/. There's several others out there. I just had that one bookmarked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) library; see [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

Answer (score 2):

I believe Stack Overflow is using the [Google code prettifier](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Answer (score 1):

Questions about stackoverflow should be on on Meta but to answer your question take a look here

[Source code syntax highlighting on stackoverflow wmd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22542/source-code-syntax-highlighting-on-stackoverflow-wmd)