# How does SO do its syntax highlighting for code?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does SO syntax highlight citations so well?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-does-so-syntax-highlight-citations-so-well)

The syntax highlighting on StackOverflow is excellent. How do they do it?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-does-so-syntax-highlight-citations-so-well/14670

Comment: Did you attempt to search the site at all?

Comment: @Rich B: Great, now he's going to post a question about how to search.

Comment: @Pesto: How to open eyes ?

Comment: Thanks, guys, very friendly. Is calculating and highlighting diffs the same thing as citation highlighting or syntax highlighting? 

Editing peoples questions until they match an answer and then closing them must be fulfilling in ways I can't fathom.

Comment: @Jim: You applied 'syntax highlighting' as a tag. There is no code diff utility on SO. Slow down and write understandable questions if you want better answers.

Comment: @Jim: Were you referring to the diffs in the revisions list of a particular question?

Comment: @snicker Yes, it seems to deal with strikethrough and syntax highlighting of code on the same line, which ends up with clearer and more attractive results than I get from most diff programs.

Comment: @Jim, you should revert your question and try and get it reopened.

Answer (score 1):

This is just [Google prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).