# Is Stack Overflow's code color-coding script available?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Stack Overflow syntax highlight citations so well?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664)

I hope I'm asking this in the right place.

I really admire the color-coding script that the Stack Overflow text editor uses (the one that encodes and parses JavaScript code and other languages and wraps keywords in spans for CSS color styling). Is that a proprietary script or one that might be publicly available (or a proprietary script that Stack Overflow would be willing to share)?

It would come in really handy for internal application documentation.

Comment: It’s really remarkably poor on Perl.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Comment: nice! Thanks for the link. This will definitely come in handy.