# Where can I find a documentation for the prettify code script stackoverflow uses?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [StackOverflow's code color-coding script. Available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33256/stackoverflows-code-color-coding-script-available)

The formated code tag seems to be rendered with a JavaScript library called prettify. Is this something Open Source and where can I find a documentation?

Answer (score 2):

It a Google product:

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

Comment: thanks! I was really confused with WMD...