# What syntax highlighter does Stack Overflow use?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Stack Overflow syntax highlight citations so well?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-does-so-syntax-highlight-citations-so-well)

What syntax highlighter does Stack Overflow use?

I was browsing Meta Stack Overflow and I couldn't find the answer. (Feel free to close this one if it has a duplicate.)

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-does-so-syntax-highlight-citations-so-well

Answer (score 4):

As much as people dis our search...

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=syntax+highlighter

.. *I'm just sayin'*

Comment: I've NEVER dissed the search, just the results :) +1.

Answer (score 1):

Google Prettify. Source: [How does Stack Overflow syntax highlight citations so well?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-does-so-syntax-highlight-citations-so-well/14670)

(So, yeah, this is a duplicate.)