# What syntax highlighting library is used on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, javascript, syntax-highlighting, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is Stack Overflow's code color-coding script available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33256)
>   [What syntax highlighter does Stack Overflow use?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40870)
>   [How does Stack Overflow syntax highlight citations so well?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664)

I like highlighting here at Stack Overflow very much. Which library is being used for that?

Comment: This might be more welcome on Meta.SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Code Prettify. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints/75019#75019)