# How can I specify a language in a code block?

Tags: support, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Interface options for specifying language prettify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify)

I don't know how Markdown recognizes which language to use in code blocks. Sometimes it doesn't guess right. Can I specify a code block's language myself? If so, how?

Comment: It used Google Prettify http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14664/how-does-so-syntax-highlight-citations-so-well.  Your question pretty much dups this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-language-hints, and lots of others.

Comment: Is this really a feature request? It doesn't sound like one. If you want a possibility to choose the language yourself, then this is a dupe. Right now, only the algorithm determines the "correct" language.

Comment: @Shog9 it seems wrong to close a **specific question** by calling it a duplicate of a **generic question**, even if the answer is somewhere in there.

Comment: The answer has changed over time, @BobStein-VisiBone - the linked question is kept up to date, this answer probably won't be.

Comment: `<!-- language: «lang-or-tag-here» -->` in stackoverflow, ` ```«lang-or-tag-here» ` elsewhere...

Comment: BTW, should add `<!-- language: xxx -->` before code block ```, not inside.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

(Note, I'm answering the body of your question, not the title)

The tags on your question are used to determine the language for the code blocks.

I'm not sure how that works if you have multiple languages in your tags, or for code golf questions.

Comment: You can't specify any tag in answer, isn't it?

Comment: Yup, see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting

Comment: https://github.com/googlearchive/code-prettify/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Use `<!-- language:javascript -->` or   `<!-- language:typescript -->`