# Can I set a specific language format when when writing in a code block?

Tags: support, asking-questions, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to specify a language in code block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74176/how-to-specify-a-language-in-code-block)

Hi, is there an option to set the language when formatting code in a StackOverflow question ?

I know that there are Wiki's that allow you to add a tag that declares what language the code is in, and that helps with formatting the code. Is there anything similar here ?